# SQL Server Express vs. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

What does SQL Server Express offer that MySQL do not?

PS: I'm comapring the two free Editions (MySQL and SQL Server **Express**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good article but highly geared towards MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html

Also a decent article but highly geared towards SQL Server

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/competitor-compare.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compare-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MySQL expert, but its capacity, features and performance are very much depending on the table type you select (InnoDB, MyIsam + others). It's like having different products under the same hood.
Your choice might also be impacted by the platform that will run the db: Sql Server will only run on Windows.
There are other free choices, like Oracle Database 10g Express Edition, DB2 and others.